# What is the main role of MessageChannel in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know when should I choose this solution.

Is it just for solving cross domain communications on client browser?

Comment: read this:https://dev.opera.com/articles/window-postmessage-messagechannel/

Comment: yeah, it's just for solving that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channel Messaging offer two-way and direct communication between browsing contexts. The DOM is not directly exposed with cross-document messaging but at each end there is a port. The data being sent from one port is the input in other and vice-versa. This will be a good [article](http://www.webgranth.com/html5-web-messaging-fresh-tutorial-for-cross-document-messaging) for you. And another [article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/working-with-channel-messaging-apis-in-html5.html)